# Laravel Email Duplicate Check Job

Tags: php

**register.blade.php**

```
@if(session('duplicate_email'))
        <script>
            alert("{{ session('duplicate_email') }}");
        </script>
    @endif
    
    <script>

        $(".btn-submit").on('click', function () {
            var formData = $('.myForm').serialize();  
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            
            var emailRegex = /^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
            if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
                alert("유효하지 않은 이메일 형식입니다.");
            }
       
            $.ajax({
                url: '/register',  
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,   
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);  
                    window.location.href = "/login";
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(error); 
                }
            });              
        });   
        
    </script>
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Admin;
use App\Http\Requests\StorePostRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register', [
            '1' => 1
        ]);
    }


    public function store(StorePostRequest $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $existingUser = Admin::where('email', $email)->first();

        if ($existingUser) {
            $request->session()->flash('duplicate_email', '이미 사용 중인 이메일입니다.');
            return redirect()->route('register');
        }

        Admin::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'), 
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        ]);

        return view('auth.login');
    }
}
```

**StorePostRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StorePostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ];
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            'password_confirmation' => '비밀번호 확인',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => '이름을 입력해주세요.',
            'email.required' => '이메일을 입력해주세요.',
            'email.email' => '유효한 이메일 주소를 입력해주세요.',
            'password.required' => '비밀번호를 입력해주세요.',
            'password.min' => '비밀번호는 최소 6자 이상이어야 합니다.',
            'password.confirmed' => ':비밀번호가 일치하지 않습니다.',

        ];
    }
}
```

In the process of implementing the membership sign-up function in the Laravel project, it is a task to open an alert popup by checking for duplicate emails.

After passing the data to the server through ajax and checking if there is a store method value in the RegisterController.php file, the duplicate_email value is sent through an alert notification in the View.

When looking at the code above, if there are any incorrect grammar codes, please reply.

Comment: So you want show duplicate email error message ?

Comment: Yes, if there are duplicate emails, I want to handle them as an alert notification on the client side.

Comment: I applied the code, but it didn't work out well and I got a 400 (Bad Request) error on the chrome network side.

Comment: Please show your route for the store function

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if ($existingUser) 
    {
     $request->session()->flash('duplicate_email', '이미 사용 중인 이메일입니다.');
     return redirect()->route('register');
    }
```

To this

```
if ($existingUser) 
{

 return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Duplicate email'
    ], 400);

}
```

And modify this in your error handling

```
error: function(response)
{
  Alert(response.responseJSON.message); // this will show duplicate email message
}
```